# Creating line on map using DotSpatial C#

Tags: c#, dotspatial

To create a line on map using DotSpatial, I wrote below code but it returns

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate' to 'DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate'

```
#region "Class level varibales"
//the line layer
MapLineLayer lineLayer = default(MapLineLayer);
//the line feature set
FeatureSet lineF = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Line);
int lineID = 0;
//boolean variable for first time mouse click
bool firstClick = false;
//boolean variable for ski path drawing finished
bool hikingpathPathFinished = false;
#endregion


private void buttonDrawnLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //remove any existing path
    foreach (IMapLineLayer existingPath in map1.GetLineLayers())
    {
        map1.Layers.Remove(existingPath);
    }
    lineF = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Line);

    //ski path is not finished
    hikingpathPathFinished = false;

    //initialize polyline feature set
    map1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

    //set projection
    lineF.Projection = map1.Projection;
    //initialize the featureSet attribute table
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("ID");
    lineF.DataTable.Columns.Add(column);
    //add the featureSet as map layer
    lineLayer = (MapLineLayer)map1.Layers.Add(lineF);
    LineSymbolizer symbol = new LineSymbolizer(Color.Blue, 2);
    lineLayer.Symbolizer = symbol;
    lineLayer.LegendText = "Hiking path";
    firstClick = true;
}

private void map1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //if ski path is fininshed, don't draw any line
    if (hikingpathPathFinished == true)
        return;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //left click - fill array of coordinates
        //coordinate of clicked point
        Coordinate coord = map1.PixelToProj(e.Location);
  
        //first time left click - create empty line feature
        if (firstClick)
        {
            //Create a new List called lineArray.
            //In List we need not define the size and also 
            //Here this list will store the Coordinates
            //We are going to store the mouse click coordinates into this array.
            List<Coordinate> lineArray = new List<Coordinate>();

            //Create an instance for LineString class.
            //We need to pass collection of list coordinates
            LineString lineGeometry = new LineString(lineArray);

            //Add the linegeometry to line feature
            IFeature lineFeature = lineF.AddFeature(lineGeometry);

            //add first coordinate to the line feature
            lineFeature.Coordinates.Add(coord);
            //set the line feature attribute
            lineID = lineID + 1;
            lineFeature.DataRow["ID"] = lineID;
            firstClick = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //second or more clicks - add points to the existing feature
            IFeature existingFeature = lineF.Features[lineF.Features.Count - 1];
            existingFeature.Coordinates.Add(coord);
            //refresh the map if line has 2 or more points
            if (existingFeature.Coordinates.Count >= 2)
            {
                lineF.InitializeVertices();
                map1.ResetBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //right click - reset first mouse click
        firstClick = true;
        map1.ResetBuffer();
        lineF.SaveAs("c:\\2009 Falls\\linepath.shp", true);
        MessageBox.Show("The line shapefile has been saved.");
        map1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        //the ski path is finished
        hikingpathPathFinished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thanks Ian. I want to create a line on map with mouse clicks using dotspatial. in this part of code I am getting error . Coordinate coord = map1.PixelToProj(e.Location);